# Setting batch parameters with NSMetadataQuery or MDQuery

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, spotlight, nsmetadataquery

It would be helpful if someone shares how batching a query is done using -

```
- (void)setNotificationBatchingInterval:(NSTimeInterval)timeInterval
```

when used with NSMetadataQuery or by using

```
void MDQuerySetBatchingParameters (
    MDQueryRef query,  
    MDQueryBatchingParams params
);
```

structure when used with MDQuery class.

My understanding of batching is that -
NSMetadataQueryGatheringProgressNotification/kMDQueryProgressNotification observers are notified depending on the values given in timeInterval/MDQueryBatchingParams.

When I pass 0.001f to the value of timeInterval, I expected it to notify the method every 1msec which is not the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that these values when given to MDQueryBatchingParams structure worked the way I wanted except that max_num values were of no use. There were notifications every milli second so that I could control the results.

```
MDQueryBatchingParams params;
params.first_max_num = 100;
params.first_max_ms = 1;
params.progress_max_num = 1;
params.progress_max_ms = 100;
params.update_max_num = 100;
params.update_max_ms = 100;
```